# php call function when another function is done and return to UI

Tags: php

i have two functions. One of them returns json to the UI and the other one saves json in database

```
public function test1(){
  return $x;
 }
 public function test2(){
 //save $X in database;
 }
```

In the UI, i have a form that calls test1 and shows $X via ajax in browser. After that, function test2 must be run automatically

Comment: Any reason why you need to display before storing? The other way around would be much simpler.

Comment: because i want dont any time to store

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two AJAX calls. The first one gets the value to display. Then if the user says it's OK to save it, the second one saves it in the database. You can save the value in a session variable.

script1.php:

```
$_SESSION['result'] = $obj->test1();
echo json_encode($_SESSION['result'];
exit;
```

script2.php:

```
$obj->setX($_SESSION['result']);
$obj->test2();
exit;
```

Comment: But he wants to display before storing.

Comment: I've updated the answer to describe how to do it with two AJAX calls.

Comment: let me explain ,my customer call function test1 then function test1 return $x,we have to use "return" and u now after return any script cant use